# How to enable SSH?

Tags: ssh

so I wont to access my Ubuntu 18 server in WinSCP becouse I need to upload some files, but I don't know how to enable this!

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Have you looked at the documentation?   https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html.en